# Rasa chatbot : "Failed to install frontend dependencies. Check logs for details."

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x

**I have an issue with Rasa X. Installation part is successful but when I executed "rasa x" command I'm getting below error and a new browser window is opened and showing cat images with text: "Frontend compiling-and now ...we wait"**

```
(venv) user@DELL-Admin:~/PycharmProjects/Rasa_chatbot$ rasa x 
Starting Rasa X in local mode... 
 Building frontend (development mode)... 
make: *** No rule to make target 'install-frontend'.  Stop. 
Failed to install frontend dependencies. Check logs for details. 
Process Process-2: 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in
    _bootstrap
        self.run()   
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   
File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Rasa_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasax/community     /api/blueprints/interface.py", line 65, in run_build
        "Frontend install failed! Check the logs for details.",   
File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Rasa_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasax/community/api/blueprints/interface.py", line 37, in _write_index_html
        os.mkdir(path) 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/PycharmProjects/Rasa_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasax/community/api/blueprints/../../../../../../src/frontend/build' /home/user/PycharmProjects/Rasa_chatbot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasa/core/training/dsl.py:422: UserWarning: Found unknown intent 'greet' on line 2. Please, make sure that all intents are listed in your domain yaml.   docs=DOCS_URL_DOMAINS,

    The server is running at http://localhost:5002/login?username=me&password=weZD6Q9KLFjUN

    2020-03-28 13:28:24.557697: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
```

> When I execute "rasa train" and "rasa shell" commands then I have no
>   errors but when I execute the "rasa x" command then I'm getting error?

Comment: I am also facing the same, even the same is not resolved on community as well, its been couple of days now

Comment: @Akshay I came to know this is the bug in latest version of rasa (1.9.3) , rasa sdk (1.9.0) and rasa-x(0.27.1). Hope further version can fix it.

Comment: even I am getting the error- “Frontend compiling…and now…we wait”.
Screenshots posted here- https://forum.rasa.com/t/installation-of-rasa-and-rasa-x-on-ubuntu/25768/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here comes the latest version of Rasa x just update your Rasa x with
>   below command:
>   I tested it, its working fine. Just update it

```
pip install rasa-x==0.27.2 --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
```

> Activate virtual environment before running this code.

```
Note Configuration:

Rasa - 1.9.3
Rasa SDK - 1.9.0
Rasa x - 0.27.2
```

> Don't install Rasa X versions(0.27.0 & 0.27.1) dependencies are not
>   supported.

Comment: Hi @Jainmiah, Do you know how to have a default welcome message in RASA ??

Answer (score 0):

Rasa X latest version (0.27.1) has bug, so just follow the steps below to make Rasa X work-

1. Uninstall “rasa”, “rasa-sdk”, & “rasa-x” (if you have it installed)
2. Install Rasa X 0.26.3 by this command-

   `pip install rasa-x==0.26.3 --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple`

   - (**automatically this will install the compatible rasa version**)
   - (also make sure to use pip / pip3 as per your default python)
3. create a demo bot by “rasa init”
4. type “rasa x”

Comment: Hi Aayush,i tied as per above now i am getting below error mentioned here:                                                            https://forum.rasa.com/t/when-trying-to-run-rasa-x-got-revision-not-found-error/24304

Comment: these are the rasa versions i have now: rasa==1.8.3
rasa-sdk==1.9.0
rasa-x==0.26.3

Comment: 1. @Akshay, Did you uninstall your previous rasa, rasa-sdk & rasa-x versions which were installed ?
2. Which OS are you using ?
3. Are you using Anaconda distribution of Python ?? What is your Python version ?

Comment: Hey Aayush, its working now, rasa introduced new version of rasa-x  i.e 0.27.2. there was bug in rasa-x 0.27.1

Comment: Hi @Akshay, Do you know how to have a default welcome message in RASA ??

Comment: What default message you are looking for?

Comment: @Akshay, This is what I am looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/q/61176574/5662552